# Meteor package load order

Tags: javascript, meteor

The order I add packages on Meteor makes any difference in the result ? Lets say I use bootstrap 3 and accounts ui with bootstrap 3, if I add the latter first or vice versa would work the same way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Meteor the package order that you add them in does not matter.

There is a module in meteor called linker that analyses each packages dependencies to ensure that the dependencies load first.

For example: If *bootstrap-3* is a dependency of *accounts-ui-bootstrap-3* then even if *bootstrap-3* was added after, it would be loaded first.

Comment: What about things that do not have explicit dependency? For example, one `admin` package is overriding the bootstrap styles (where bootstrap is not dependency and optional), and in my package I am also overriding the bootstrap styles (bootstrap, once again, is optional - no point in forcing the user). These two packages do not depend on each other either - now what is the loading order?

Comment: I you install https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection before https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks you will automatically run into errors. Could be an isolated case,but am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to test for or access an optional dependency from within a package.  You can test for it's existence by testing if Package['author:package'] is defined.  The problem is the load order.  I got around it temporarily by editing the packages file in .meteor and moving the optional dependency package higher up in the list.  I don't think it's a good long term fix though.  This should be a Meteor feature suggestion, if it's not already.

Answer (score -1):

Each package has a `package.json` file that lists what other packages it requires. This practice ensures that packages load in a proper order. Read these files to troubleshoot load-order issues.

Comment: that should be `package.js`. Not json. see: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs